# Display the rerun value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var items = [];
 var myfunc= function ()
    {
        $.getJSON("a.txt", function (data1) {
            for (key in data1) {
                items.push(key);
            }
        });
        return items[0] + " test";
        }
```

with alert(myfunc()), I can't see the first element of my items Array. I declared that to be global but i get this:
"undefined test"  what could be the reason?
Thanks

Comment: getJSON is asynchronous. so `items` is still undefined when the function is returned

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async

Comment: Thanks for the answer, That make sense.